# NameSpaces added in view web.config but no intellisence is available on view cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am using MVC 5 with glass mapper in sitecore 8.1 but this issue seems to be the same for all MVC versions.

I have to use many references in my each view so i decided to shift them in View/web.config like shown below

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <!-- Glass Mapper Namespaces -->
        <add namespace="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="Glass.Mapper.Sc" />
        <add namespace="Glass.Mapper" />
        <add namespace="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc" />

        <!-- Sitecore Namespaces-->
        <add namespace="Sitecore" />
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation" />
        <!--<add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics"/>-->
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions"/>

        <!-- xxx Namespaces-->
        <add namespace="xxx.SC.GlassMapper.ViewModel.Layout.Layouts.Renderings.Components.Global.Navigation"/>
        <add namespace="xxx.SC.GlassMapper.ViewModel.Layout.Layouts.Renderings.Components.Global.Site"/>
        <add namespace="xxx.SC.GlassMapper.ViewModel.Layout.Layouts"/>
        <add namespace="xxx.SC.GlassMapper.Model.Pages"/>
        <add namespace="xxx.SC.Shared.References"/>

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

It works fine if I reference them on the view itself by `@using` attribute, but now it's not working after I moved the references to view/web.config file.

Here's the view:

```
@inherits GlassView<Main>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="@Model.LanguageIsoCode">

    @Html.Sitecore().Rendering(LayoutIDs.Head, Model.HeadDataSource)
    @Html.Sitecore().Rendering(LayoutIDs.StyleSheets)

</head>
<body lang="@Model.LanguageIsoCode">
    @Html.Sitecore().Rendering(LayoutIDs.Header, Model.MainNavigationDataSource)

    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("PlaceholderMain")

    @Html.Sitecore().Rendering(LayoutIDs.Footer, Model.FooterDataSource)
    @Html.Sitecore().Rendering(LayoutIDs.Scripts)
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to restart Visual Studio once or twice. I had exactly the same issue and it helped.

Comment: Try setting Copy Local to true on your references, if you haven't already.

Comment: I have this problem , close a `vs` and open again , its ok :)

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have restarted visual studio many times even deleted all temporary, pre-fetch files etc and restarted machine as well but still no luck

Comment: @BenGolden required assemblies which are referenced in web config are set to Copy Local.

Comment: @UthmanRahimi normally it works but not in my current case i have even restarted my system still no luck same solution is working with one of my  colleague and not for other team members including me.

Comment: I've had this issue before and I closed all the files that were opened, cleaned my solution, rebuild (while every file was closed), restarted visual studio and it worked. Won't hurt to try.

Comment: @DenisRadinski I have tried it many time event restarted my system, removes temporary and cache files etc but no luck.
Then i set all assemblies "Copy Local = false" and again to true it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on this the other day. Credit to Jammy Kam.

All you need to do it set each Sitecore dlls to CopyLocal = true in Visual Studio.

[image]

http://www.waitingimpatiently.com/intellisense-issue-when-using-sitecore-local-nuget-files/

Comment: @dnstommy all assemblies that are referenced(Sitecore or Glass Mapper) in solution are set to "Copy Local = true"

Comment: @dnstommy I set all assemblies "Copy Local = false" and again to true it seems work some time and sometime not.
It does not seems to be permanent/reliable solution but good workaround for now.